# Cannot resolve method 'setTitle(java.lang.String)' android studio

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

This is the java code where error (**Cannot resolve method 'setTitle(java.lang.String)'** and same for **setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled**s) rises:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar).setTitle("Register");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

toolbar xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="@color/purple_500">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

For the Toolbar I have imported `import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;`

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `setTitle` you have to use `getSupportActionBar()` to retrieve the ActionBar:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Register");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```